Why does an expendable Starship launch cost only $100 million?
Even the Falcon Heavy with a third the payload costs $150 million. And yet we have Payload Research saying that an expendable Starship launch costs less?

First the $100 million figure is only an estimate, probably based on starships being mass produced. Even though it's an expendable figure, it may include previous reuse of the booster, reducing the cost.
Falcon heavy is three rockets strapped together, this is potentially more expensive than making a single rocket body which is three times larger. It has 27 engines which isn't much less than the super heavy booster.
Starship is made from stainless steel which is potentially cheaper and easier to work with than the aluminium used in falcon heavy.
The Raptor engine has been designed from the beginning to be mass produced with the lessons that SpaceX have learnt from the Merlin, per unit it should end up being cheaper than the Merlin. SpaceX have estimated costs to eventually be $250,000. I can't find any references for Merlin unit cost but there are estimates of between 1 and 2.5 million dollars.
